# Ошибки при компилировании OpenGL проекта

Tags: c++, opengl

Скопировал исходный код из одного видеоурока:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.75, 0.75);
  glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glVertex2f(0.75, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.25, 0.75);
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glVertex2f(0.50, 0.25);
  glVertex2f(0.50, 0.75);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(240, 240);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 740);
  glutCreateWindow("Test");
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

**при компилировании выдается куча ошибок:**

> "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/[Makefile-Debug.mk](http://Makefile-Debug.mk) QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
> make[1]: Вход в каталог `/home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test'
> "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test
> make[2]: Вход в каталог`/home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test'
> mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
> g++-4.6     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `display()':
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to`glClear'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glBegin'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to`glColor3f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to`glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glColor3f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to`glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to`glColor3f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to`glVertex2f'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `glEnd'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to`glFlush'
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to`glutInit'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to`glutInitWindowSize'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to`glutCreateWindow'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `glClearColor'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to`glMatrixMode'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to`glOrtho'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
> /home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to`glutMainLoop'
> collect2: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
> make[2]:  ***[dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test] Ошибка 1
> make[2]: Выход из каталога `/home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test'
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Ошибка 2
> make[1]: Выход из каталога`/home/knoxx/NetBeansProjects/test'
> make:***  [.build-impl] Ошибка 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2, общее время: 194ms)

Что не так? для библиотеки `openGL` устанавливал `freeglut3` и `freeglut3-dev`.

Comment: Вопросы по сборке проекта с OpenGL будут каждую неделю повторяться один-в-один? Разберитесь наконец-то с ключами командной строки для g++. Посмотрите свой предыдущий вопрос и проанализируйте ответы. И не забудьте, что freeglut != glut и требует немного других инклюдов и командной строки.

Comment: Так то вопросы, которые я задаю, несколько разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте линковщику аргумент -lglut (без всяких IDE этот код можно собрать так: g++ -lglut main.cpp -o main)

Comment: не помогает

Answer (score 4):

Подключите библиотеки `opengl-а` и `glut-а`.

Comment: то есть это какие?
в случае с opengl прям вот так:
#include <opengl>   ?
но у меня нет такой библиотеки